# Unable to restart Postgres Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

For my rails application, every time I try to do rails console, I get this error:

```
server: Connection refused (PG::ConnectionBad)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I suspected that this was because my postgres server was down.. So I used the lunchy gem to stop and start my server. However, I still keep getting the same error.
`lunchy stop postgres`
`lunchy start postgres`

I also tried this:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`
and got `server starting`
but when I do this: `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status`, it does not work because I get a `pg_ctl: no server running`

Why is this the case?

Comment: Maybe you should look in `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` for a hint

Comment: What is the output of `ps -ef | grep postgres`?

Comment: @geekazoid it is   501   675   270   0 12:01AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep postgres

Comment: Ok, so probably you are not running postgres at all. What OS are you in?

Comment: @geekazoid I am using mac

Comment: It was working fine all along, and then my computer crashed inexplicably, and then I started facing this issue

Comment: I really can't help you since I'm not used to development in Mac. But the problem is that you don't have postgres running. 

What does `lunchy start postgres` outputs?

Comment: /Users/xxx/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: Operation already in progress
started homebrew.mxcl.postgresql

Comment: If restarting your machine does not help, try uninstalling the `pg` gem and then re-installing it using the `--with-pg-config` option. Set it with:

`bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config`

Comment: Before going and trying random stuff, you need to confirm how you installed PostgreSQL and where its files and logs are. Then you can identify the correct way to start it, and if it fails, check the log files. Since you're using Ruby you probably installed PostgreSQL using Homebrew ... right?

Comment: @CraigRinger yes, I checked my log files already and the last lines in the log files are LOG:  received smart shutdown request
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down. Yeah I installed in using homebrew